# How to get a table's all references in powerdesigner?

Tags: reference, powerdesigner

I have a lot of tables in powerdesigner.
But I want to know one table's references. Do you know how to get them?

> tips: 
>  
>   powerdesigner version:15.1.0

Comment: Where? In a report, on the screen, on the Properties dialog, via scripting?

Comment: @pascal I've found it in the property dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it in the table view.

> properties-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer you've found to your question.

Comment: Do you know how to add reference between tables?